# How to get the length of the longest Line in a File in C

Tags: c

this is my first Question here so im grateful for every kind of Help.

Im trying to get the length of the longest Line in a File, so i can later calloc it and read the whole File in. My first attempt was Dynamic, but it didnt work.

My Code till now is:

```
FILE *inputData;
inputData = fopen("input.txt", "r");
char *input = NULL;
int longestLinelength = 0;
while(fscanf(inputData,"%[^\n]", input) != EOF) { 
    if(longestLineLength<strlen(input)){
        longestLineLength=strlen(input);
    }
}

fclose()
```

This code unfortunetly leads to a memory access error.

Comment: `input` is a NULL pointer and you want to write to it, this causes a crash in the application.

Comment: "(I tried with realloc but it didnt work)." show that as a [mre] please. Reads like it is closer to success than bluntly reading into a NULL pointer as shown here.

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user (or text file) input. Forget `scanf()` exists.

Comment: You could use `getc()` and maintain a counter and a max value, which are (re)set when an `\n` is encountered. Nu buffers needed, so the longest line can be *very* long...

Comment: Please don't deface your post.  If one of the answers addressed your question, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: suggest using `getline()`

Comment: Just a comment unrelated to your problem: Try not to read your file in two passes if it can be done in one. What if the file changes content between passes? And not every file is seekable.

Answer (score 6):

```
size_t longestLine(FILE *fi)
{
    size_t largest = 0, current = 0;
    int ch;

    if(fi)
    {
        while((ch = fgetc(fi)) != EOF)
        {
            if(ch == '\n')
            {
                if(current > largest) largest = current;
                current = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                current++;
            }
        }
        if(current > largest) largest = current;
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: This has the benefit of not having to allocate anything. It'd be my prefered way of doing it.

Comment: _...later calloc it and read the whole File in._ So now you read the whole file a second time? Not a big problem, but not ideal. Do you know how you want to store that file? Maybe as a 2D game board?

Comment: `largest` or `longest`?

Comment: @chqrlie longest.

Comment: Clean method.  shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75309657/troubles-with-pointers-when-reading-from-a-txt-file/75312249#75312249)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not with realloc, but with a misunderstanding of how things work.

It would be best to read carefully what [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) does. And how pointers work.

`input` is a NULL pointer and you want to write to it, this causes a crash in the application. `scanf` needs allocated memory to write to, it does not allocate it itself. Generally I would suggest to use [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of scanf as it is better to handle. The formating options of `scanf` can be done after you read it with `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this help this is based on the book The C Programming Language.

First we need a main function to get the lines in the file

```c
int get_file_line(char line[], int maxline, FILE *fptr) {
    int ch, i;
    for (i = 0; i < (maxline - 1) && ((ch = getc(fptr)) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); ++i) {
        line[i] = ch;
    } 

    if (ch == '\n') {
        line[i] = ch;
        ++i;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Then we will store the data into a new array of chars

```c
void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (from[i] != '\0') {
        to[i] = from[i];
        i++;
    }
    
}
```

And finally in the main function we gonna open the file and use the previous functions

```c
FILE *ptr;
const char *file_name = "your_file.txt";

ptr = fopen(file_name, "r");
while ((len = get_file_line(line, MAXLINE, ptr)) > 0) {
    if (len > max) {
        max = len;
        copy(longest, line);
    }
}
fclose(ptr);

if (max > 0) {
    printf("longest: %s\n", longest);
    printf("len : %d\n", max);
}
```

All together

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 

int get_file_line(char line[], int maxline, FILE *fptr) {
    int ch, i;
    for (i = 0; i < (maxline - 1) && ((ch = getc(fptr)) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); ++i) {
        line[i] = ch;
    } 

    if (ch == '\n') {
        line[i] = ch;
        ++i;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (from[i] != '\0') {
        to[i] = from[i];
        i++;
    }
    
}

int main() {
    int len, max = 0;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    FILE *ptr;
    const char *file_name = "your_file.txt";


    ptr = fopen(file_name, "r");

    while ((len = get_file_line(line, MAXLINE, ptr)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }

    fclose(ptr);

    if (max > 0) {
        printf("longest: %s\n", longest);
        printf("len : %d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
      #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    #define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 4096
    
    static void process_file(char *filename);
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      int q;
    
      if(argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s <files>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
      }
    
      for(q = 1; q < argc; q++) {
        process_file(argv[q]);
      }
    
      return 0;
    }
    
    void process_file(char *filename) {
      char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
      FILE *file;
    
      char line_val[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
      int line_len = -1;
      int line_num = -1;
      int cur_line = 1;
    
      file = fopen(filename, "r");
      if(file == NULL) {
        return;

  }

  while(fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file) != NULL) {
    int len_tmp = strlen(buf) - 1; 

 
    if(buf[len_tmp] == '\n')
      buf[len_tmp] = '\0';

    if(line_len < len_tmp) {
      strncpy(line_val, buf, len_tmp + 1);
      line_len = len_tmp;
      line_num = cur_line;
    }

    cur_line++;
    /*printf("%s", buf);*/
  }

  fclose(file);

  if(line_num < 1) {
    return;
  }

  printf("%d:%s:%d:%s\n", line_len, filename, line_num, line_val);

}
```

Comment: The question asked how to find the length of the longest line, so as to be able to allocate enough space for it.  Here you are just *assuming* the longest possible length is (and allocating space of) 4096.  So your solution kind of begs the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).