# Troubles with pointers when reading from a txt file

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, fread

Im trying to print out the strings from a txt file in order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for command line args
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./read infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create buffer to read into
    char buffer[7];
    // Create array to store plate numbers
    char *plates[8];

    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int idx = 0;


    while (fread(buffer, 1, 7, infile) == 7)
    {
        char buffer2[7];
        // Replace '\n' with '\0'
        buffer[6] = '\0';
        strcpy(buffer2, buffer);

        // Save plate number in array

        plates[idx] = buffer2;
        idx++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", plates[i]);
    }


}
```

The pasted code just writes one and the same string over and over again, and I cant for the life of me figure out what Im doing wrong. When I debug the "while" method, I see that the buffer updates keep overwriting every entry to the plates array.

Comment: `plates[idx] = buffer2;`???  How many `buffer2` variables are there?  What happens to it when the loop terminates?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can we find a duplicate? Or will you make an answer?

Comment: I don't think this is a pointer problem. You probably need a dynamic allocation when adding a plate to your plates array.

Comment: @Yunnosch  I can't find a good duplicate with a complete and proper answer, and I don't have time to compose one right now.  :-(

Comment: BTW: if you're reading from a text file, you shouldn't use `fread` in the first place, but rather `fgets`. Your usage of `fread` only works if all lines in the text file file contain exactly  6 characters, as soon as one line contains more or less than exactly 6 characters everything gets misaligned. And you also should check if `fopen` fails and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Im trying to print out the strings from a txt file in order."*

As noted in comments `fread()` as used in your implementation is not the best way to read lines in a text file.

Answering these 2 questions (at minimum the first one) will provide important values to help in declaring and initializing the right sized (and shaped) buffers for reading lines from a file...

- What is the longest line in the file?
- How many lines are in the file?    (may be optional if not storing all lines)

The following example(s) can be accomplished knowing only the answer to the first question, but knowing the answer to the second would be useful if it was necessary for example to store all of the lines into an array of strings. (This is out of scope here as you did not list that as a requirement for your code)

Unless you are comfortable with making an assumption on the maximum line length, i.e. hard-coded...

```
char line[guessed_max_line_length] = {0};
```

...a run-time assessment to determine the length of the longest line in the file is necessary to size the buffer such that it can safely contain lines that will later be read from file. Once [this assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69072314/645128) is done, use the length of the longest line to create a line buffer during run-time. (dynamically allocate memory):

```
char *line = malloc(max_length + 1);
memset(line, 0, max_length + 1);
```

Using these methods, (and providing the implementation linked above) your code can be simplified to the following adaptation....

```
//prototype to get max line length in file
size_t longestLine(FILE *fi);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for command line args
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./read infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(infile)
    {
        size_t max_length = longestLine(infile); //see linked implemenation from above
        rewind(infile);//suggest adding this line to longestLine() implementation.
        char *line = malloc(max_length + 1);
        if(line)
        {
            memset(line, 0, max_length + 1);
            while(fgets(line, max_length, infile))
            {
                fputs(line, stdout);
                //or alternatively
                //printf("%s", line);
            }
            free(line);
        }
        fclose(infile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this for loop

```
while (fread(buffer, 1, 7, infile) == 7)
{
    char buffer2[7];
    // Replace '\n' with '\0'
    buffer[6] = '\0';
    strcpy(buffer2, buffer);

    // Save plate number in array

    plates[idx] = buffer2;
    idx++;
}
```

you declared a local array with automatic storage duration

```
    char buffer2[7];
```

that will not be alive after exiting the loop. And all elements of the array `plates` are set by the address of the first element of the array `buffer2`. That is within the for loop  they all point to the same extent of memory.

After exiting the loop the pointers will be invalid.

You need to allocate character arrays dynamically and their addresses to assign to the elements of the array `plates`.

Also pay attention to that the function `fread` does not read a string. So this statement

```
buffer[6] = '\0';
```

overwrites the last character stored in the array.

Comment: I am not even sure whether the local `buffer` is even technically guaranteed to be on the same address in each iteration. I do not see a reason/benefit of compiler changing it in between, but there is no guarantee, or what do you think? In this case, as demonstrated by the described output, it seems to be the case.

Comment: @Yunnosch The stack for local variables is allocated when a function gets the control. I doubt that within the function the variable will be reallocated.

Comment: Really appreciate your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic allocation should fix your problem. You could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for command line args
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./read infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create buffer to read into
    char buffer[7];
    // Create array to store plate numbers
    char *plates[8];

    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int idx = 0;


    while (fread(buffer, 1, 7, infile) == 7)
    {
        // Replace '\n' with '\0'
        buffer[6] = '\0';

        // Save plate number in array
        plates[idx] = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        strcpy(plates[idx++], buffer);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", plates[i]);
        free(plates[i];
    }
}
```

> The pasted code just writes one and the same string over and over again, and I cant for the life of me figure out what Im doing wrong. When I debug the "while" method, I see that the buffer updates keep overwriting every entry to the plates array.

[@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) gave you an explanation for this:

> that will not be alive after exiting the loop. And all elements of the array plates are set by the address of the first element of the array buffer2. That is within the for loop they all point to the same extent of memory.